# Is there a Rails way to automatically generate sequential IDs for fields of the same type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that will generate an XML file. There are multiple fields for "items" that I would like to manipulate individually with JQuery using the ID as the selector. I have the following HAML code to generate the fields:

```
- 5.times do
  = f.text_field :item, multiple: true, class: 'form-control'
```

Is there a Rails way to automatically set the IDs to item_1, item_2, item_3, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
- 5.times do |x|
    = f.text_field "item_#{x+1}", multiple: true, class: 'form-control'
```